# Return function is not working properly in my python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Return is not working after one cycle of program.

```
def check(n):
    if n != 'y':
        check (n=input("Enter a character"))
    else:
        return n

n=check(n=input("Enter a character"))
print(n)
```

Comment: Consider a ternary operator here: `def check(n):
    return n if n == 'y' else check(n=input("Enter a character"))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate a return value after the recursive call:

```
def check(n):
    if n != 'y':
        return check(input("Enter a character"))
    else:
        return n

n=check(n=input("Enter a character"))
print(n)
```